# After connecting 3rd external monitor typing lag starts, Macbook Pro 2016

Tags: display, thunderbolt, displayport

Have macbook pro 2016 and connected 3rd external monitor. Then all monitors including macbook screen have typing lag. But let me clear about there is **no mouse** lag OR when I move the application window like chrome or jet brains IDE like pycharm **no window movement lag**.

But when I start typing in IDE or browser's search bar. I can see clearly that **there is typing lag**. And about the monitors and cables. I have a LG Ultrawide 5K and Apple Display 27inch (apple display connected VIA mini display port to thunderbolt by apple official tool)

I am not very sure why macbook pro 2016 having such a problem on? One of the cable is LG's original and the other one is apple's thunderbolt changer. By the way as grafic card Pro has **Radeon Pro 460**

Any idea what is causing this problem and how to solve this?

Comment: is the mouse connected via bluetooth or USB?

Comment: it's connected via bluetooth also keyboard connected via bluetooth. apple's magic keyboard and mouse @X_841

Comment: @yepsolutely Try moving one or more of your BT devices to USB. I'd bet that the BT channel is saturated with data.

Comment: As you said. there was a BT data transfer issue on the keyboard. I connected it via usb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the exact same issue and the moment I connected my apple wireless mouse to the USB, the problem went away completely!!